# VisualBasic script for Excel (String concat)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to help my friend with rather long work - he has to concatenate a lot of strings in spreadsheet (we are talking about tens of hundreds from what I heard). To save him from that, I decided to write a VB script for him (despite not writing in VB since few years and pretty much not without any knowledge how should it work). After some debugs we came to this code:

```
Sub Concatenate

Dim LCounter As Long
Dim FinalValue As String

FinalValue = ""

For LCounter = 1 To Rows.Count
   Set NumberCell = Cells(LCounter, 1)
   Set StringCell = Cells(LCounter, 2)
   FinalValue = FinalValue & StringCell.Value
   If IsEmpty(NumberCell) Then
      Cells(LCounter, 3).Value = FinalValue
      FinalValue = ""
   End If
Next LCounter

End Sub
```

In the end, code won't compile - we get an 424 error (Object required). I tried to change NumberCell to NumberCell.Value, but in vain. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

[To those who want to know how should it work - there are a plenty of Strings in B column. In column A we have some numbers - if there is a number present, we should concatenate all strings in range right after last number to current number and write result in C column, on the same row number appeared.]

Comment: Why VBA? If you just want to concatenate, then you can use normal formulas. Even if you want to concatenate only if column A is number, still you can do it with normal formulas

Comment: Mostly because I don't know how to do it properly with Excel formulas, I rarely do anything in any kind of spreadsheets. VBA was closest to what I do on every day (Java), so I tried writing a script in it. Apparently, VBA is not my strong side as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all your variables, then you wouldn't have problem... always use `Option Explicit`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Concatenate
'decare all variables you are using
Dim NumberCell As Range, StringCell As Range, LCounter As Long

For LCounter = 1 To Rows.Count
    Set NumberCell = Cells(LCounter, 1)
    Set StringCell = Cells(LCounter, 2)

    If IsEmpty(NumberCell) Then
        Cells(LCounter, 3).Value = NumberCell.Value & StringCell.Value
        'I don't know what you want exactly, so here you have more options
        'Cells(LCounter, 3).Value = StringCell.Value & NumberCell.Value
        'this would be equivalent to your code, but makes no sense to me
        'Cells(LCounter, 3).Value = StringCell.Value
    End If
Next LCounter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you expected, it will loop through Column B, and concatenate all the cells until it finds something on Column A, in which case it will write the concatenated string into Column C in the row where the string/number was found in Column A.

It is also good practice to declare the Worksheet you are working with, so VBA doesn't assume the ActiveSheet instead:

```
Sub Concatenate()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column B
Dim LCounter As Long
Dim FinalValue As String

FinalValue = ""
For LCounter = 1 To LastRow
   NumberCell = ws.Cells(LCounter, 1)
   StringCell = ws.Cells(LCounter, 2)
   FinalValue = FinalValue & StringCell
   If Not IsEmpty(NumberCell) Then
      Cells(LCounter, 3).Value = FinalValue
      FinalValue = ""
   End If
Next LCounter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using logic in square brackets:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Concatenate()
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyArea As Range
    Dim iCell As Range, lRow As Long, FinalValue As String
    'Change "MySheet" accordingly
    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")
    'Calculate last row of column B
    lRow = MySheet.Range("B" & MySheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop through each area of blank cells in column A
    For Each MyArea In MySheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
        'Loop through each cell in this area
        For Each iCell In MyArea.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(MyArea.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Cells
            'Add Cell value to FinalValue
            FinalValue = FinalValue & iCell.Value
        Next
        'Put string into according cell
        MyArea.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 2) = FinalValue
        'Clear FinalValue
        FinalValue = ""
    Next
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Here is the sample:
[image]